# Creating code bank for my team

Tags: version-control

I have some code snippets in different software programming languages and want to share them with my team. I want to use a code bank (repository) to store these codes and the team members only (not any person) can download them. I don't know what tools are available? I need a free tool and can be accessible from a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
http://www.snippetmanager.net/

Comment: thanks, but I need something like an upload centre to upload my codes on it and my team could download whatever they want.